# Add custom attribute in jQuery UI Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

In jQuery UI autocomplete, I just want to add my custom attribute. But, I tried below code. It's not working for me. It was replace whole `<li>` html content.

**What I tried :**

```
.data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            return $("<li>").attr( "data-id",item.value).append(item.label).appendTo(ul);
        };
```

**Output of above code :**

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-1" tabindex="0" style="display: none; width: 562px; top: 592px; left: 767px;">
   <li data-id="220">Que 1</li>
   <li data-id="219">Que 2</li>
   <li data-id="218">Que 3</li>
   <li data-id="217">Que 4</li>
</ul>
```

**Rendered HTML (By Default Code of [jQuery UI Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)):**

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-1" tabindex="0" style="display: none; width: 562px; top: 593px; left: 767px;">
   <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a id="ui-id-2" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Que 1</a></li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a id="ui-id-3" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Que 2</a></li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a id="ui-id-4" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Que 3</a></li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a id="ui-id-5" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Que 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Expected Output :**

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-1" tabindex="0" style="display: none; width: 562px; top: 593px; left: 767px;">
   <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a id="ui-id-2" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1" data-id="220">Que 1</a></li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a id="ui-id-3" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1" data-id="221">Que 2</a></li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a id="ui-id-4" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1" data-id="222">Que 3</a></li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a id="ui-id-5" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1" data-id="223">Que 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's not clear what's not working for you.

Comment: I want autogenerate rendered html. Just want to add data-id. You can see in actual result. But, If I tried my code which I mentioned in question that changed li structure.

Comment: Check my updated question

Comment: So when you say "Actual output", do you mean **desired output**? Maybe?

Comment: Yes. Right..... Sorry, My mistake.

Comment: @User863 In your fiddle, check output without .data("ui-autocomplete") code and check html in console. In that, I want to add attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep everything the same as the original output and then add the `data-id` you have to build the whole `<li>` again, since you're *overriding* the default render function.

So you would do:

```js
.data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    const htmlstring = `<li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1"></a></li>`;
    const $li = $(htmlstring);
    const id = $(ul).find('li').length + 1;
    $li.find('a').attr("data-id", item.value).attr("id", id).html(item.label);
    return $li.appendTo(ul);
};
```

Comment: Cool..!! Is it possible to do without remove id?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example which I used in a recent project. Hope this will help you out

```
var $project = $('#search-input');
    $project.data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
            var $li = $('<li>'),
            $li.attr('data-id', item.value);
            $li.append('<a href="http://example.com/product/'+item.id+'"><span>');
            $li.append('<span class="autocomplete_detail">'+item.value+'</span>');    
            return $li.appendTo(ul);
          };
```